# Will access to shared resources in LAN be recorded or not?

Tags: windows-xp, local-area-network, network-share

If it's recorded, where can I check who has accessed the shared resources?

Answer (score 2):

It won't automagically you need to configure auditing on the server!

Comment: Additionally, the audit logs are unwieldy and verbose.

Answer (score 0):

To see who has files open on a particular share you can also use the shared folders snap-in. You can add it through MMC (called Shared Folders) or you can access it via the Run menu with the command, "fsmgmt.msc". I know this isn't what you asked for but it still might be useful to you. Good luck!